# Rubymotion: adding footer to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have troubles adding a footer to an UICollectionView using Rubymotion and RMQ.

Adding just a header works fine, but just a footer or both header and footer don't work.

I use this

```
COLLECTION_HEADER_ID = "SectionHeader"
...
cv.registerClass(SectionHeader, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: COLLECTION_HEADER_ID)
...
def collectionView(view, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:kind, atIndexPath:path)
      view.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier:COLLECTION_HEADER_ID, forIndexPath:path)
```

In this case, the header is printed.
I then add

```
COLLECTION_FOOTER_ID = "SectionFooter"
...
cv.registerClass(SectionFooter, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: COLLECTION_FOOTER_ID)
```

And change my viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function:

```
def collectionView(view, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:kind, atIndexPath:path)
  if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter
    return
    view.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier:COLLECTION_HEADER_ID, forIndexPath:path)
  end
    return view.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier:COLLECTION_HEADER_ID, forIndexPath:path)
end
```

Running rake, I get no error, but I also get no footer...
 In `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` function, the "kind" is always `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`, I don't get why...

If I try to only display a footer, I get

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil ((null))'
```

"kind" is once again `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`

UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader ? Are you forced to use a header to use be able to use a footer ?

Any hint on this ?